# any_instance should_receive not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a code like this:

```
@dns = "#{params[:domain].split('/').reverse.join('.')}.#{params[:zone]}"
w = Whois::Client.new
@r = w.query(@dns)
```

with a route:

```
match "domains/:zone/*domain" => "domains#show"
```

I'm using [Whois Gem](http://www.ruby-whois.org/)

and I want to test is, so I have a test:

```
it "should query 'google.com.ua' from /ua/com/google" do
    get :show, :zone => 'ua', :domain => 'com/google'
    dns = "google.com.ua"
    Whois::Client.any_instance.should_receive(:query).with(dns)
end
```

And as a result I get:

```
Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: query
```

Where can be the problem? I'm 100% sure that `.query` is called

Comment: http://sscce.org/. Your question is short, but not self contained; write a complete script so people can run it and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you might be setting the expectation after you've already called the query method?

Comment: damn, I get it, my fault. Doh

Comment: `should_receive` checks the future, not the past

Comment: @Uko: see why it's important to post a complete example ;-)

Comment: I had the same problem too. I was using `Model.any_instance.should_receive(:method)` as if was an expectation. (It sort of is, but as @ArtShayderov says, it checks the future, not the past).